# Which Folder do i put my frontend files in Spring boot. Is it Src/main/resource or Src/main

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-frontend

Im confused on where to put all my Front-end files like HTML and CSS as Well JS and it frontend framekwork stuff like react. Do i put it in the resource folder or the scr/main and create a folder call "webApp" and host all my HTML files there?

Does it matter which I use?

Comment: `src/main/resource` is for resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in the `src/main/resource` folder by default. Also you can follow those approachs:

- Generate a project with [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) and see the content.
- Do a research on [github](https://github.com/search?q=fullstack%20spring%20boot) with the key word **"fullstack spring boot"**, you will find many examples and differents types of project organization
- Use [Docker Compose](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-mysql-react-docker-compose-example/) to deploy your **Front End** (on NodeJS) and your **Back End** (as a Spring Boot application) in differents images

Answer (score 1):

`src/main/resource`  or some organised order structure module wie inside `src/main/resource` is good practice and easy to find by IDEs and WARs unpacking / loading paths.